# Continuity of $g(x) =\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$ proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> Let $f$ be a function with the property that every point of discontinuity is a removable discontinuity. Define $g(x) = \lim_{y\to x}f(y)$. Prove that $g(x)$ is continuous.

My proof:

Let $x_0, x_1, ...$ be the discontinuities of $f$

Then $g(x) = \lim_{y \to x}f(y)=f(x)$ when $x \neq x_0, x_1, ...$ as the function is continuous everywhere else

Suppose $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = l$$

$$\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0 \; \text{ such that } \; 0<|x-a| <\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-l| < \varepsilon$$

Choose $\delta'=min(\delta, |x_0-a|, |x_1-a|, ...)$

Then $$0<|x-a|<\delta' \Rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon \; \text{ and } \;|f(x)-l|=|g(x)-l|$$
as $x_0, x_1,...$ are not in the interval and $0<|x-a|<\delta$

So

$$|g(x)-l|<\varepsilon \;\text{ for } \; 0<|x-a|<\delta' \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to a}g(x)=l=\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$$

Since $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=g(a)$,

$$\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = g(a) $$
which implies g is continuous.

Comment: Your proof is suffering from two issues: (1) When you write the discontinuity points by $x_1, x_2, \ldots$, you are implicitly assuming that there are only at most countably many such points when, in fact, there can be uncountably many such. (2) Even if such points are at most countable, they can form a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so that your choice of $\delta'$ is always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my comment for the issues in OP's proof. Here, let me provide a proof of the statement.

---

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. For each $x_0$, choose $\delta = \delta_{x_0} > 0$ such that

$$ \forall x  \quad : \quad 0 < |x - x_0| < \delta_{x_0} \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x) - g(x_0)| < \varepsilon/2. $$

The key idea of the proof is that, using the assumption, you can (almost) replace $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ at the expense of slightly increasing the bound.

Let $x_0$ be arbitrary. Then for each $x$ in $(x_0 - \delta_{x_0}, x_0 + \delta_{x_0})$, we can find $x'$ such that

$$ x' \in \bigl( (x_0 - \delta_{x_0}, x_0 + \delta_{x_0}) \setminus \{x_0\} \bigr) \cap \bigl( (x - \delta_{x}, x + \delta_{x}) \setminus \{x\} \bigr). $$

Using this $x'$,

$$ |g(x) - g(x_0)|
\leq |g(x) - f(x')| + |f(x') - g(x_0)|
< (\varepsilon/2) + (\varepsilon/2) = \varepsilon $$

and therefore the claim follows.